# How to extract content with preg_match_all for specific divs without id or class only

Tags: php, html, extract, preg-match-all

I like to load some data from an external .html file using preg_match_all!
Data is stored in a table containing 2000 lines like this:

```
<DIV STYLE="top:605px; left:252px; width:70px" Class="S8">4:02</DIV>
<DIV STYLE="top:605px; left:287px; width:43px; height:15px" Class="S6"></DIV>
<DIV STYLE="top:605px; left:295px; width:70px" Class="S8">4:55</DIV>
<DIV STYLE="top:325px; left:295px; width:70px" Class="S8">6037</DIV>
<DIV STYLE="top:325px; left:330px; width:43px; height:15px" Class="S6"></DIV>
<DIV STYLE="top:325px; left:338px; width:70px" Class="S8">6040</DIV>
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to use preg_match_all but 
is it possible to search for specific style values ? eg. find all divs with left attribut between 240px and 300px and return inner div data ?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is messy at best. Have a look at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php). For starters: [DOMDocument::loadHTML()](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the regex string `"/<DIV STYLE=".*?left:(2[4-9][0-9]|300).*?>(.*?)<\/DIV>/"`, `preg_match_all` will return an array with three sub arrays. The first will be the whole `div`. The second will be the `left` style value. The last one will be the inner html of the `div`.